# What is the difference between these typedef uses?

Tags: c

What is the difference between:

```
typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} S1, *S1PTR;

((S1PTR)structure)->b)
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} S1;

((S1*)structure)->b)
```

Comment: Besides the obvious fact that they use a different set of characters to denote the same thing, the whole point of typedef is that there's no difference.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: You could create the pointer typedef from the structure one manually if you wanted to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's also worth considering [Herb Sutter's take on this](http://www.drdobbs.com/conversationsa-midsummer-nights-madness/184403835) ;)

Comment: ***"Confusion is the dark side of programming. Too many `typedefs`, poor naming choices — these all lead to..."***

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between these typedef uses?

No difference to the compiler.

---

It is a style difference.

`(S1*)structure` looks like a cast to a pointer - which it is.

`(S1PTR)structure` does not readily look like a cast to a pointer - yet it is a cast to a pointer.

`*` speaks louder than `...PTR`.

---

Also: The use of uppercase only identifiers hints of a `#define`, which it is not.

---

Code to your group's coding guidelines.  Ones I use would not condone `S1PTR` here.